# String object to ArrayList object

Tags: java, arrays, collections

the user enters 2 sting, which are stored in variable a and b. Now there are many ArrayList present in the program, we have to check if there is an ArrayList present with the name stored in variable a.
So how can I do that?

```
public static void root(String a,String b)
{
    ArrayList chicago=new ArrayList();
    chicago.add("newyork");
    chicago.add("new jersy");
    chicago.add("dallas");

    ArrayList buffalo=new ArrayList();
    buffalo.add("arlington");
    buffalo.add("california");
    buffalo.add("dallas");

    ArrayList newyork=new ArrayList();
    newyork.add("chicago");
    newyork.add("paris");
    newyork.add("nigara");

    ArrayList stations=new ArrayList();
    stations.add(chicago);
    stations.add(buffalo);
    stations.add(newyork);

    if(stations.contains(a))
    {


    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe using [`ArrayList#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can be found by consulting the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) and [Collections Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: Can you maybe provide a small example of the code that clarifies your question?

Comment: seems like you are already in a correct path. just complete your `if` statement

Comment: a is a String object and I am checking it against ArrayList object, though it does not give any compile time error but it does nothing, the control does not enters the if block.

Comment: @KunalSachdev how did you know it doesn't enter the `if` block if your `if` block is empty?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use something like a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`.  The keys in the `HashMap` could be the strings that you are using as names here.

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

ArrayList<String> chicago=new ArrayList<>();
chicago.add("newyork");
chicago.add("new jersy");
chicago.add("dallas");
map.put("chicago", chicago);
```

and so on.

Then the condition that you want to check will be

```
if (map.containsKey(a) && map.get(a).contains(b)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you (although not an optimum solution):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Test2 {
    public Test2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test a String.
        String test = "newyork";
        String test2 = "dallas";
        root(test, test2);
    }

    public static void root(String a,String b)
    {
        ArrayList<String> chicago=new ArrayList();
        chicago.add("newyork");
        chicago.add("new jersy");
        chicago.add("dallas");

        ArrayList<String> buffalo=new ArrayList();
        buffalo.add("arlington");
        buffalo.add("california");
        buffalo.add("dallas");

        ArrayList<String> newyork=new ArrayList();
        newyork.add("chicago");
        newyork.add("paris");
        newyork.add("nigara");

        ArrayList<ArrayList> stations=new ArrayList();
        stations.add(chicago);
        stations.add(buffalo);
        stations.add(newyork);

        // Go through each ArrayList.
        Iterator<ArrayList> arrStations = stations.iterator();
        while(arrStations.hasNext()){
            ArrayList<String> tmp = arrStations.next();
            if(tmp.contains(a)){
                // a is in the ArrayList.
                System.out.println("String '" + a + "', is in");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think, this answer is best for my side

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a nested ArrayList. If you want to find if the a exists you gonna have to loop through the nested array list

```
public static void root(String a,String b)
{
  ArrayList chicago=new ArrayList();
  chicago.add("newyork");
  chicago.add("new jersy");
  chicago.add("dallas");

  ArrayList buffalo=new ArrayList();
  buffalo.add("arlington");
  buffalo.add("california");
  buffalo.add("dallas");

  ArrayList newyork=new ArrayList();
  newyork.add("chicago");
  newyork.add("paris");
  newyork.add("nigara");

  ArrayList stations=new ArrayList();
  stations.add(chicago);
  stations.add(buffalo);
  stations.add(newyork);


 for(Object o : stations) {
    //cast the object back to an arrayList
    ArrayList l = (ArrayList) o;

    if(l.contains(a))
    {

        System.out.println("Found");
        break;
    }else {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
}
```